# Loop all the number with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, loops

I have used simple loop to get all number, but I have tried to put all number that have been looped into HTML, but all I get is the last number into the HTML. But I want it to give all the numbers and not only the last number. How to get all numbers published on HTML with jQuery?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $(.div_class_name).html(i); 
}
```

But my question is, why doesn't it give us all number? I know that it is possible with JavaScript but how about jQuery?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The `.html()` function replaces (over-keys) what was last written.

Try using `.append(i)` instead.

Comment: Btw, I am new here, so can I ask if there is some private message function on this site?

Comment: There isn't as far as i am aware.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are overwriting the numer that is already there. You shoud do it like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $(".div_class_name").html($(".div_class_name").html() + i); 
}
```

or this:

```
$(".div_class_name").html("")    
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $(".div_class_name").append(i); 
}
```

Comment: I think the second one was much easier to remember!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(.div_class_name).append(i);
```